# SQL Sub queries Seat Exchange

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand how this subquery works. The questions are as follows

Mary is a teacher in a middle school and she has a table seat storing students' names and their corresponding seat ids.The column id is continuous increment.
Mary wants to change seats for the adjacent students.

```
 SELECT
(CASE
    WHEN MOD(id, 2) != 0 AND counts != id THEN id + 1
    WHEN MOD(id, 2) != 0 AND counts = id THEN id
    ELSE id - 1
END) AS id,
student
FROM
seat,
(SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS counts
FROM
    seat) AS seat_counts
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

I am trying to understand the how the above query works. So in the CASE it checks if the id is odd or even and checks against the count to see if it is the last element. But how does the ORDER BY ASC work? Because for the first time it selects student Dorris and id 2. but then how is id 2 assigned to Abbot. Thanks.

SQL Table

```
id   | student 

1    | Abbot   
2    | Doris   
3    | Emerson
4    | Green   
5    | Jeames
```

The Result will look like

```
id   | student

1    | Dorris
2    | Abbot 
3    | Green 
4    | Emerson
5    | Jeames
```

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Comment: I understand there are many ways to do it. But can you explain how the query is working especially how the id is being switched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the results by removing ORDER BY statement. When you remove ORDER BY statement, result will be:

```
2   Abbot
1   Doris
4   Emerson
3   Green
5   Jeames
```

Which is completely right for your case. Basically, your query just alters id's values based on the CASE statement. When you add ORDER BY id ASC statement it just orders the result above.

Comment: If you don't have an order by there is guarantee this would be the order (the results would always be the same, just the order of the lines is unknown.)

Answer (score 1):

OK what this is doing is the following -- if an id number is odd and it is not the max number then add one to it, otherwise subtract one from it.

It should be clear that would swap all but the last pair.

I think it is badly written I would write it like this:

```
WITH student_count(max) as
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  seat
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN student_count.max != id AND MOD(id, 2) != 0 THEN id + 1 
    WHEN student_count.max != id AND MOD(id, 2) = 0 THEN id - 1 
    ELSE id
  END AS id,
  student
FROM seat
CROSS JOIN student_count
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select name,
       case when mod(seat_id,2) = 1 and seat_id <> (select max(seat_id) from students) then seat_id + 1 
            when mod(seat_id,2)= 0 then seat_id - 1
            when mod(seat_id,2) = 1 and seat_id = (select max(seat_id) from students) then seat_id
       end swap
from students
```

Comment: This is the best way I could find to do it . Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the future, it's best to use code blocks so that your code is more legible.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN MOD(id, 2) != 0 AND counts != id THEN id + 1
        WHEN MOD(id, 2) != 0 AND counts = id THEN id
        ELSE id - 1
    END) AS id,
    student
FROM
    seat,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS counts
    FROM
        seat) AS seat_counts
ORDER BY id ASC;
```